# Selenium is not selecting the correct value

Tags: java, selenium

Im using selenium to test a web page which has a select option and one input type text.

Manually and using the selenium IDE, it works correctly, but when I export the test case to Java Junit, i can see the dropdown click, but selenium is not selecting the value, it is just expanding the dropdown.

What can i do?

Lets check my code:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("type")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Celcius");
```

Consider my form, like:

```
<form action="doit">
    <select name="type" id = "type">
        <option value = "fail"> Fail </option>
        <option value = "celcius"> Celcius </option>        
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="num" id="num">
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe it's due to the space before and after the text? Why don't you consider `selectByIndex` or `selectByValue` to improve precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this method wont work. This may happen if the text between the option tags have spaces before and after the tags. 
Eg.

1.`<option> Fail </option>`
2.`<option>Fail</option>`

In the above example 1 and 2 are different.
So you can use like,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("type")).click();     // this will expand the list
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='type']/option[contains(text(),'Celcius')]")).click();
```

Also try to click directly. It work if the element is vivible,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='type']/option[contains(text(),'Celcius')]")).click();
```

Comment: None works :( I fell that is some problem with my Selenium java code... Using Interface it works well but at java unit case, it doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

driver.findElement(By.id("type")).sendkeys("Celcius");